# JavaFX - SelectionModel of CheckListView

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

**Problem Description**
I have a CheckListView with several items(checkboxes). I changed the Selection mode *(code below)* to allow multiple selections. However, when I select multiple rows, like in the picture below, and press SPACE, only the 'current selected row' changes state.

**I want/need to :** when I press space, toggle all selected row states.

I tried looking into handlers but im confused to what to change.

**Any help is greatly appreciated.**

[image]

```
        @FXML
        private CheckListView<String> checkListPermissoes;


        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            ...  checkListPermissoes.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple workaround how to do it, simply register a keyListener to the list and when you press Space handle the items which are not handled by JavaFx:

The code:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML private CheckListView<String> list;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        list.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        list.getItems().addAll("Apple", "Lemon", "Orange", "Banana");

        list.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.SPACE)) {
                revertCheck(list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices());
            }
        });

    }

    private void revertCheck(ObservableList<Integer> selectedIndices) {
        selectedIndices.forEach(index -> {
            // If needed to skip the selected index which is handled by JavaFx
            if (!index.equals(list.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex())) {
                if (list.getCheckModel().isChecked(index)) {
                    list.getCheckModel().clearCheck(index);
                } else {
                    list.getCheckModel().check(index);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`.fxml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import org.controlsfx.control.CheckListView?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="checklist.Controller">
<CheckListView fx:id="list"/>
</AnchorPane>
```